# Double quotes in php mail

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send newsletter but when I entered text like:

```
2nd year, 3rd Special Edition “A Tribute” of 7sisters.in has been released.
Dear Sir / Madam,

Welcome to "7sisters.in".
```

The output is:

```
2nd year, 3rd Special Edition â€œA Tributeâ€ of 7sisters.in has been released.
Dear Sir / Madam,

Welcome to "7sisters.in".`
```

I followed the answer here:

> [Correctly encode characters in a PHP mail form ("I'm" turns to be "I\'m")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726189/correctly-encode-characters-in-a-php-mail-form-im-turns-to-be-i-m)

My PHP code is:

```
$to = $allEmails[$i];
$subject = $sub;
$message = $msg;
//$message .= '<p>To unsubscribe , click here <a href="http://www.7sisters.in/index.php?menu=unsubscribe&email='.$to.'">Unsubscribe</a></p>';
$message .= '<br />To unsubscribe , click here ';
$message .= "http://www.7sisters.in/index.php?menu=unsubscribe&email=".$to;
$message = stripcslashes($message);


$from = $from_mail;
//$headers = "From:" . $from;

$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n" .
               "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n" .
               "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";        

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

How do I deal with double quotes properly when using mail()?

Comment: just remove stripcslashes and try, let we see

Comment: Change `iso-8859-1` to `UTF-8` and you should be fine.

Comment: i dont thing we require these  "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); and all, but not sure

Comment: @zneak I did but not still not coming !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an encoding problem: Your string is in UTF-8, but your content-type header states the charset as iso-8859-1.

If you want to send the mail in iso-8859-1, use [utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) to convert it.

Comment: Now it is coming like `2nd year, 3rd Special Edition ?€?A Tribute?€? of 7sisters.in has been released.
Dear Sir / Madam,

Welcome to "7sisters.in".`. I have changed `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` to `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Wih utf8_decode? And how did you change the charset (your comment does not contain any difference between the two lines).

Comment: So sorry...it should be `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; UTF-8' . "\r\n"; `

Comment: Ok its coming..Thanks . I missed `charset=`