# "I'm" becomes "I\'m" in PHP? (Why is a slash being added?)

Tags: php, slash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correctly encode characters in a PHP mail form (“I'm” turns to be “I\'m”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726189/correctly-encode-characters-in-a-php-mail-form-im-turns-to-be-i-m)

I'm sending an email over PHP and the text arrives with a slash right before the quotation mark:

`I'm` becomes `I\'m`

My PHP:

```
$text_message = $_POST["mymessage"];       


$message="--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"      
            ."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"
 ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" 
       ."$text_message\r\n\r\n" 
    ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"  
            ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
            ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachment\"\r\n"
."Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$attachment\"\r\n\r\n"
 .chunk_split($file)
        ."\r\n\r\n"
            ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text--\r\n\r\n";
}
```

How to get it send without receiving an extra slash?
Thanks.
Uli

Comment: @AndrewEllis So why would `stripslashes` work? (I'm trying to guide an answer). If it does work, what does that say about the value in `$text_message`?

Comment: @pst: If that's not a duplicate, nothing is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by PHP's [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) which are deprecated but, unfortunately, still enabled by default. In most cases you can disable the feature through a `.htaccess` file or even through the webhoster's control panel.

If that's not possible, it's safest to check if magic quotes are enabled through `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` before blindly using `stripslashes()`. To unescape all `$_POST[]` variables, use:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
       $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check for magic_quotes within your php.ini file, its most likely on,
You can always check for this option within php and handle the string accordingly

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
   $text_message = stripslashes($_POST["mymessage"]);
}else{
   $text_message = $_POST["mymessage"];
}
```

Also instead of using `\r\n` you should use `PHP_EOL` then its compatible with all operating systems: eg the `\r` is not required for linux

Comment: cheerfully withdrawn. Although, as it is a better answer than mine, I feel it deserves the upvotes in order to outscore me.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's down to `$_POST["mymessage"]`. What do you get if you echo `$_POST["mymessage"]` to screen?

Some webhosts will deliberately `addslashes()` to data received by `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc. as a basic protection against SQL injection.

If that is being done, you should be able to do `stripslashes($_POST["mymessage"])`