# File upload not working with $_FILES

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

In my PHP web page I have a file type input in a form and when I submit it I can get the file name which was uploaded with `$_POST['upload']` but if I use `$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']` it gives nothing -- why? How can I use `$_FILES` to get the file to attach it to my email?

Comment: have you set the form `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`? See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got nothing when you use `$_FILE` because you didn't use the `enctype` attribute on your form. Check how to use it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp).

Answer (score 5):

```
<form method="POST"  action=#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>

$path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
$tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
{
 if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
 {
    $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
}
```

Or for detailed info go here [Go Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826265/simple-php-form-attachment-to-email-code-golf)