# Sending an uploaded file as attachment to email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, attachment

I am a novice in Web designing. I need to create a form in HTML such that it asks the user to enter several fields and upload his/her resume. When he submits the form, his submissions should be email to me with his resume as the attachment with the email.
I have used PHP for sending the email. Everything works fine, except that the file is not getting attached with the sent email.

I am posting both the HTML and the PHP code, please help me..

**HTML Code: FileName: Careers.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="Careers.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name<br>
     <input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
    E-mail<br>
     <input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
        Date of Birth<br>
     <input type="text" name="db_name"><br>
        Contact Number<br>
     <input type="text" name="db_cntct"><br>
    Class 12 Marks/CGPA/Percentage<br>
     <input type="text" name="cf_board"><br>
         Graduation Marks/CGPA/Percentage<br>
     <input type="text" name="db_grad"><br>
     Post-Graduation Marks/CGPA/Percentage<br>
     <input type="text" name="cf_pgrad"><br>
        Present Employer<br>
     <input type="text" name="db_emplyr"><br>
     Date of Joining<br>
     <input type="text" name="cf_doj"><br>
        Designation<br>
     <input type="text" name="db_desg"><br>
        Current CTC<br>
     <input type="text" name="db_ctc"><br>
     Upload your Resume<br>
     <input type="file" name="attachment" size="40"><br>
Message<br>
<textarea name="cf_message"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code: FileName: Careers.php**

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_dob = $_POST['db_name'];
$field_contact = $_POST['db_cntct'];
$field_board = $_POST['cf_board'];
$field_grad = $_POST['db_grad'];
$field_pgrad = $_POST['cf_pgrad'];
$field_emplyr = $_POST['db_emplyr'];
$field_doj = $_POST['cf_doj'];
$field_desg = $_POST['db_desg'];
$field_ctc = $_POST['db_ctc'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'sachinrocksus@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Job Application from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Date of Birth: '.$field_dob."\n";
$body_message .= 'Contact Number: '.$field_contact."\n";
$body_message .= 'Class 12 Marks/CGPA/Percentage: '.$field_board."\n";
$body_message .= 'Graduation Marks/CGPA/Percentage: '.$field_grad."\n";
$body_message .= 'Post-Graduation Marks/CGPA/Percentage: '.$field_pgrad."\n";
$body_message .= 'Present Employer: '.$field_emplyr."\n";
$body_message .= 'Date of Joining: '.$field_doj."\n";
$body_message .= 'Designation: '.$field_desg."\n";
$body_message .= 'Current CTC: '.$field_ctc."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";       

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Your Job Application has been recieved. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'Careers.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed');
        window.location = 'Careers.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would handle a file upload. What gives? Have you read any tutorials on how to get this to work?

Comment: Try this link, it is the same issue more or less http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826265/simple-php-form-attachment-to-email-code-golf

Answer (score 5):

You are passing nothing as an attachment

Here i am pasting a snippet hope this will help you

```
<?php
    $fileatt = "mypdffile.pdf"; // Path to the file
    $fileatt_type = "application/pdf"; // File Type
    $fileatt_name = "mypdffile.pdf"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

    $email_from = "sales@mysite.com"; // Who the email is from
    $email_subject = "Your attached file"; // The Subject of the email
    $email_message = "Thanks for visiting mysite.com! Here is your free file.
    ";
    $email_message .= "Thanks for visiting.
    "; // Message that the email has in it

    $email_to = $_POST['email']; // Who the email is to

    $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

    $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
    $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);

    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
    $email_message .= "\n\n";

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
    //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data .= "\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

    $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    if($ok) {
    echo "You file has been sent
    to the email address you specified.

    Make sure to check your junk mail!

    Click here to return to mysite.com.";

    } else {
    die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for sharing such a piece of good code: 
Just little modification then this is the real working code.
MAKE A HTML FILE:

#### Upload File and send as email attachment

Name: 
            
        
        
            Email: 
            
        
        
            Select A File To Upload:

Same folder make a php file called mail_sender.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $name_of_uploaded_file =basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $formData = $_POST;
    getFile( $name_of_uploaded_file, $formData );

    function getFile( $filename , $formData ) {

        $allowedExts = array("csv","pdf","jpg","png","JPG","PNG","jpeg","JPEG");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv','application/jpg','image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');

        if (in_array($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'],$mimes )
        && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 2000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {      
                sendMailAsAttachment($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"],$formData);         
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file " . $extension . " {} " . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
          //echo in_array($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'],$mimes );
          }  
    }



//This function accepts post data on form submissions and prepare the email message from the form data.

    function prepareEmail( $formData ) {

        // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
        $to = "solimankhulna@gmail.com";
        $from = "solimankhulna@solimankhulna.com"; 
        $subject =""; 
        $message = "Uploaded File\n";
        $message .= "Name :". $formData['name']."\n";
        $message .= "Email Address :". $formData['email']."\n";
        $headers = "From: $from";

        // boundary 
        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

        // headers for attachment 
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

        // multipart boundary 
        $message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

        $emailData = array (
            'to' => $to,
            'from' => $from,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'headers' => $headers,
            'message' => $message
        );

        return $emailData;

    }

    function prepareAttachment( $filename ,$fileorgname) {
        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $attachContent = '';
        $file = fopen($filename,"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($filename));
        fclose($file);
        $cvData = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $attachContent .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$fileorgname\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fileorgname\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $cvData . "\n\n";
        $attachContent .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
        return $attachContent;

    }

    function sendMailAsAttachment( $filename, $fileorgname, $formData ) {

        $emailData = prepareEmail( $formData );
        $attachContent = prepareAttachment( $filename,$fileorgname );
        $message = $emailData['message'].$attachContent;
        $ok = @mail($emailData['to'], $emailData['subject'], $message, $emailData['headers']); 
        if ($ok) { 
                echo "<p>mail sent to " . $emailData['to'] . "!</p>"; 
        } else { 
                echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
        } 
    }



?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This function send upload file as attachment.Please refer the tutorial for html code and step by step explanation.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/send-upload-file-email-attachment-php/

```
function pepareAttachment( $filename ,$fileorgname) {

   $attachContent = '';
   $file = fopen($filename,"rb");
   $data = fread($file,filesize($filename));
   fclose($file);
   $cvData = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
   $attachContent .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$fileorgname\"\n" . 
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fileorgname\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $cvData . "\n\n";
  $attachContent .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
  return $attachContent;

}

function sendMailAsAttachment( $filename, $fileorgname, $formData ) {

$emailData = prepareEmail( $formData );
$attachContent = prepareAttachment( $filename,$fileorgname );
$message = $emailData['message'].$attachContent;
$ok = @mail($emailData['to'], $emailData['subject'], $message, $emailData['headers']); 
if ($ok) { 
        echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
} else { 
        echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you're not getting any attachment processed in your `PHP` part. 
This [tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html) might help you walk through the steps one by one.