# PHP form with checkboxes, radio buttons and file attachment

Tags: php, forms, attachment

I'm having a nightmare with this PHP form where a user can fill it in, attach a doc/pdf and submit. After trying to sort it out with previous code I've used, I've stripped it out and think I should just start again in the hope you geniuses can help!

Here is the HTML of contact.php:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contact" id="contact">

<p>Job Title:*<br />
<input name="position" type="text" /></p>

<p>Nationality:*<br />
<select name="nationality">
  <option value="">-- select one --</option>
  <option value="Afghan">Afghan</option>
  <option value="Albanian">Albanian</option>
  <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
  <option value="Zambian">Zambian</option>
  <option value="Zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>Which country are you currently living in?*<br />
<select name="country">
<option value="">-- select one --</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Africa">Africa</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
</p>

<label class="radio" for="checkRight">Yes/No question?</label><br />
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="right" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="right" value="No" /> No
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="right" value="N/A" /> Not applicable

<p>Yes/No question?<br />
<select name="continue">
<option value="">-- select one --</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>Select your resorts:<br />
Resort 1<input name="res1" type="checkbox" value="Resort 1" />
Resort 2<input name="res2" type="checkbox" value="Resort 2" />
Resort 3<input name="res3" type="checkbox" value="Resort 3" />
Resort 4<input name="res4" type="checkbox" value="Resort 4" />
Resort 5<input name="res5" type="checkbox" value="Resort 5" />
Resort 6<input name="res6" type="checkbox" value="Resort 6" />    
</p>

<p>Don't send form unless this is checked:* <input type="checkbox" name="parttime" value="Yes" /></p>

<p>Date of arrival: <input name="arrive" id="datepick" /><br />
Date of departure: <input name="depart" id="datepick2" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/datepickr/datepickr.js"></script>
<link href="assets/scripts/datepickr/datepickr.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">
new datepickr('datepick');
new datepickr('datepick2', {
});
</script>


<p>Name:*<br />
<input name="name" type="text" /></p>

<p>E-mail:*<br />
<input name="email" type="text" /></p>

<p>Telephone:*<br />
<input name="telephone" type="text" class="ctextField" /></p>

<p>Upload CV (Word of PDF formats only):<br />
<input type="file" name="cv" class="textfield"></p>

<p><input name="submit" value="Submit Enquiry" class="submitButton" type="submit" /><div style="visibility:hidden; width:1px; height:1px"><input name="url" type="text" size="45" id="url" /></div></p>

</form>
```

By the way, the date boxes work so excuse the Javascript in there!

To prevent SPAM I've used a trick where there's a hidden URL field which must be left blank for the form to submit which you can see in the PHP.

Below is where I'm at with the PHP which is placed above the header of contact.php...

```
<?php

if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
$position = $_POST['position'];
$arrive = $_POST['arrive'];
$nationality = $_POST['nationality'];
$parttime = $_POST['parttime'];
$depart = $_POST['depart'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

$to = "me@mywebsite.com";
$subject = "Recruitment Application";

$message = $headers;
$message .= "Name: " . $_POST["name"] . "\r\n";
$message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: My Website <application@mywebsite.com>' . "\r\n";



$message= "
";

$url = stripslashes($_POST["url"]);
if (!empty($url)) {
header( 'Location: http://www.go-away-spam-robots.com' );
exit();
}

if (!isset($warning)) {
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header( 'Location: http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/sent.php' );
}

}

?>
```

I would like to make pretty much all the field compulsory so if a field is left empty (other than the hidden URL field), a warning message is displayed next to that field.

Also I would like the file upload field to attach to the email that is sent to me and have the results come through to me in a table format.

Can anyone help me get my form working?

Thank you and I hope to hear from you!

SM

Comment: What were the results of you using your posted code?

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for the reply. It doesn't submit any results at the moment...!

Comment: There are a few errors and will post an answer below, which I tested. The file attachment part, you will need to look into that. I don't write code, I fix what is given.

Comment: So, how are you making out, have you had a look at my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

> ## ✓ Tested

---

There are a few errors and is posted below, which I tested. The file attachment part, you will need to look into that. I don't write code, I fix what is given to work with.

What is happening is that you're overwriting the message with this line.

```
$message= "
";
```

so everything gets thrown away from the previous `$message` variable.

First, start by removing this line `$message = $headers;`

and replacing it with this line `$message ="";`

then removing this line

```
$message= "
";
```

---

> ## ✓ New body of code:

---

```
$message ="";
$message .= "Name: " . $_POST["name"] . "\r\n";
$message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: My Website <application@mywebsite.com>' . "\r\n";
```

---

> ## ✓ Regarding file attachments

---

In order to attach a file, your form does not contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

It must be included and looking like the following:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contact" id="contact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I suggest you Google "how to attach a file to Email in PHP" or "Email file attachment in PHP".

You can have a look at an example and an accepted answer [**here on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1673281/1415724) on how to achieve this.

---

> ## ✓ Example file attachment PHP handler

---

Here is an example PHP handler on how to attach a file.

Source: http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email with attachment';
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

<?php
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```